# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n-1}\over(n-1)!}\cdot{e^{-xn}-1\over e^{xn}-1}=-e^{-x(1-e^{-x})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n-1}\over(n-1)!}\cdot{e^{-xn}-1\over e^{xn}-1}=-e^{-x(1-e^{-x})}$$

My try:

We know

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}=e^x$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-xn}-1\over e^{xn}-1}={1\over 1-e^{x}}$$

How do I use these two formulae to arrive  at the top formula?

Let and try letting $x=\ln{y}$ then we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\ln{y}^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}\cdot{y^{-n}-1\over y^n-1}=-y^{{1\over y}-1}$$

Still can't see anything obvious step to do next, any hints?

Comment: $(e^{-xn}-1)/(e^{xn}-1)=e^{-nx}$,$x^{n-1}e^{-nx}=(xe^{-x})^{n-1}e^{-x}$

Comment: @kingW3 You have forgotten a minus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{e^{-xn}-1}{e^{xn}-1}=\frac{1}{e^{nx}}\frac{e^{-xn}-1}{1-e^{-nx}}=-e^{-nx}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{\left(n-1\right)!}\frac{e^{-xn}-1}{e^{xn}-1}=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{\left(n-1\right)!}e^{-xn}
 $$ $$=-e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}e^{-xn}=\color{red}{-\exp\left(-x+xe^{-x}\right)}.$$

Comment: All too easy.  (+1)  And Happy Holidays Marco.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you Mark, Happy Holidays to you!

Comment: The beauty of simplicity. (+1) & Merry Christmas Marco.

Comment: @HazemOrabi Thank you! Merry Christmas! :)